# Access JSON placed in local folder when using angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using angular cli for my projects. I have placed a JSON in structure like below

src/app/data/data.json. I am trying to access it from http.get method

```
 return this._http.get('../data/data.json',
                              { headers: this.getHeaders })
            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
```

It say it cannot find the json. But same if i place JSON in assets folder it works. I dont want JSON to be placed in assets folder. Will it work if i keep the json in app folder?

Comment: I believe it should be place inside your assets folder because that is your public directory

Comment: Should work. On which path is your code in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.angular-cli.json` `"assets"` section. This way you will get your static assets output by angular cli e.g:

```
"assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    "app/data/data.json"
 ],
```

By specifying `app/data/data.json` in `assets` cli will output just a single file `data.json` in to `app/data/` folder. If you want to output all assets inside your `app/data` folder then you do this:

```
"assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "app/data"
     ],
```

> You can always check if your `static` assets getting outputed by cli by
>   running `ng  build` and checking the content of the `dist` folder.
>
> You can place you custom assets in to `assets` like
>   `assets/data/data.json` so this way you do not have to modify
>   `.angular-cli.json` as `assets` folder is already there by default

Comment: will it not work if he places the files in his app folder i guess it will any idea ?

Comment: @RahulSingh could be inside `app` could be at the same level

Comment: So i place in assets or any folder inside does not make any sense, it will be publicly visible by direct URL

Comment: It is up to you how you want to handle that. I just showed you all pissible options.