# Angular cli build versioning the Json Files

Tags: typescript, angular-cli

I read lots of images & strings needed for my webapp from `json` content present in my assets folder. So that I can change them on the fly by invalidating them.

`ng build --prod --output-hashing=all` generates a hashed file like **main.06d5672830c816025599.bundle.js**. I don't see the `json` files are versioned in the assets folder.

by changing some code the Hash for the main..js changes but the client will cache the Json if its already Downloaded.
How can i make sure the cache gets busted on client whenever i change my Json?

and main..js is more like 300KB which the client has to download even if a small part of the code changes.
is there a way to hash the files individually instead of one main..js?

Comment: *I dont see the json Files are versionized in the assets folder*, **You use the assets array in .angular-cli.json to list files or folders you want to copy as-is when building your project. By default, the src/assets/ folder and src/favicon.ico are copied over.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access JSON placed in local folder when using angular cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45582036/access-json-placed-in-local-folder-when-using-angular-cli)

Answer (score 0):

Angular build is supposed to add hashes for cache busting purposes.

Manually you would just change the name of the JSON file every time you update it, e.g. config.json?v=1, config.json?v=2, etc.

Changing the name every time you update the JSON file it will enable cache busting.

Other tools like grunt or gulp may have better options.